# Perforce error: rename would ignore changes

Tags: perforce

I am trying to rename a file. I typed in the following command

p4 rename file1 file2

but I get the error "file1 is open; rename would ignore changes". What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not seeing that.  Perforce server version 2013.1/610569 will happily rename a changed file and it will maintain the changes across the rename operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the file is not checked out in any workspace including other users workspaces before you rename it.